# EJB ObjectMapper

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, jackson, weblogic12c

I've worked on a Spring project earlier, where you can create an ObjectMapper bean.

Advantages of using a bean is the ease of testing, and the single point of configuration.

My current project involves a JEE Weblogic environment. I can't create a bean from the ObjectMapper like in Spring, because the ObjectMapper has final methods JEE doesn't like.
I tried to extend the ObjectMapper configuring it in the constructor.

I've found the ContextResolver solution for registering custom serializers in the rest interfaces, but I would like to have a reusable, dependency injected, preconfigured ObjectMapper, because we also serialize objects in other parts of the application.

Is it possible to achieve this?

If I missed something, and this is a terrible idea, I would also like to know why.

Kind regards and thanks in advance,

Johannis

Answer (score 2):

So I've found the issue and solution.

ObjectMapper has final methods which are unsupported by EJB.

The solution was to use CDI to create the ObjectMapper bean, and using @Inject for the injection:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class SerializerConfig {

    @Produces
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper();
    }
}
```

Now the ObjectMapper is injectable:

```
public class ObjectMapperUser {

    @Inject
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks to share your solution. I have the same problem. I overrided the ObjectMapperContexResolver class, but it didn't resolve my problem. Could you explain more? 
My question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73211880/error-org-codehaus-jackson-map-jsonmappingexception