# ERROR: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException

Tags: java, json, jackson, lombok

I'm using lombok + Java to otimizate the application. The class has the tags `@Data` , `@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)`, `@NoArgsConstructor`, `@AllArgsConstructor` e `@Builder` before signature's class. When I run, It shows the error below:

**ERROR:**

> org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSRuntimeException:
> org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor
> found for type [simple type, class java.time.LocalDateTime]: can not
> instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
> at [Source:
> org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$1@25e15ce5;
> line: 1, column: 188]     at
> org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.toJAXRSRuntimeException(JAXRSUtils.java:1906)
> at
> org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.convertExceptionToResponseIfPossible(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:276)

**CLASS:**

```
...

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Person {

     private LocalDateTime date;
     ...
}
```

I thougth this lombok's tags are enough. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Do you have jackon-datatype-jsr310 dependency?
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310

It looks like the problem is related with Jackson and LocalDateTime, not Lombok.

Comment: No, I don't have. I'll include and I'll write a feedback. You are rigth.

Comment: I added the dependency and the error persist. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are using a very old Jackson version.
2. To make Jackson work with Java 8 time, you need to add [jackson-datatype-jsr310](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310) dependency and register module in ObjectMapper:

```
objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

Complete working example with current Jackson version:

```
Person person = new Person(LocalDateTime.now());
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(person);
Person personDeserialized = objectMapper.readValue(json, Person.class);
```

Dependencies:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: I need to create a ObjectMapperContextResolver class. A question is when I connect this class with my especific mapper. Could you share with me some articules? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I did it and shows this error:  `org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class java.time.LocalDateTime]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)` . I think is a details. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I overrided the classes: ObjectMapperContextResolver, LocalDateTimeSerializer and LocalDateTimeDeserializer. Same error. I cannot update the version, so I need to use this one. I apprecite more suggests!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to do the same in your version of Jackson.

Comment: I'm using EJB. I understood your answer and it works in spring boot project. Thanks for your help. Your answer could help many!